# Filter JTable only one one column

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

I have a JTable and I would like to do a filter from a `JTextfield` but only filter the results based on one column and not to search all columns.

I have my JTable I can filter but my filter will filter and search every column of the table I want to restrict it to one column

Can it be done ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

listen to changes in the textFields document and set the appropriate rowFilter limited to the column you want to filter:

```
 // on document change
 RowFilter rowFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(textField.getText(), myColumn);
 table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(rowFilter);
```

(type-cast and guard against empty textfield ommitted)

Comment: Thank u very much this has done what i wanted solved solved solved

Comment: would love to vote put am not allowed to vote yet :(:(:( but thanks again

Comment: @user692808 you can accept the answer, can't you? Will augment your reputation as well as mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a master copy of all the rows (or supporting data) in the background.

When searching, take the search criteria from the text field and rebuild the table model by only adding items that match the criteria.  If the text field is empty then add all rows.

Comment: good (though not trivial to get right) for pre1.6, not since 1.6: my  general rule is to always use all the support available by any framework, the remainder is hard enough ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend envelope table model like this http://java-sl.com/envelope.html
and leave only necessary rows.

Comment: still in jdk1.5 (stone-) age ;-)